# what does this specific SQL statement mean?

Tags: sql, database, vb6, connection, ms-access-2010

I am working with a pre-existing software and the software is written in vb6 and the database it uses is Access Database, I have come across this question and I have been trying to figure out what this means for the past one and a half hours and I cannot make it out

```
select count(*) from subscriptions where M_ID=" & Trim(M_ID), Conn, 2, 2
```

specifically the "&" symbol, why is it used before, when I googled it's used as an and operator between two values, but this is only one and that  to the symbol is not in between but in front at the start, and "Conn, 2, 2" conn i get is maybe like a connection string what is 2 and 2 after it

Answer (score 2):

The & is concatenating strings in VB. There must be something missing in this piece of code as there is only one quotation mark.

```
Open "select count(*) from subscriptions where M_ID=" & Trim(M_ID), Conn, 2, 2
```

This matches the `Open` method of an [ADO RecordSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset) on connection `Conn` with CursorType and LockType both set to 2.

Comment: The missing part is probably `rs.Open "`

Comment: Rs.Open "select count(*) from subscriptions where Mem_no=" & Trim(Mem_No), Conn, 2, 2
            If Rs(0) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "This Membership Can't be Delete..Because this Membership Contains Subscriptions data..."
                Rs.Close

Comment: Update the code in your original question instead of putting the additional code as a comment.